# Place bars at specific x-axis values in a barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to represent two-dimensional data as bars, placed over the x-axis values, but `barplot()` does not allow to control x-axis placement, and `plot()` does not draw bars:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 5)
y <- 1:4
plot(x, y, type = "h")
barplot(y)
```

[Click for an image illustrating the `plot()` and `barplot()` examples.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfzjR.png)

I understand that I can plot a histogram –

```
hist(rep(x, y), breaks = seq(min(x) - 0.5, max(x) + 0.5, 1))
```

[Click for an image illustrating the `hist()` example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRlj.png)

– but the recreation of the original (non-frequency) data and the calculation of the breaks is not always as straightforward as in this example, so:

- Is there a way to force `plot()` to draw bars?
- Or is there a way to force `barplot()` to place the bars at specific values on the x-axis?

Basically, what I would like is something like:

```
barplot(y, at = x)
```

*I would prefer to use base R and avoid ggplot.*

Comment: A bar plot uses categorical values on the x axis.  To use barplot to plot a specific values then all of categories need a value even if zero. Like in this `barplot(c(1, 2,3, 0, 4), names.arg=1:5)`

Comment: @Dave2e That's a great idea, but works only if the bars are evenly spaced. What if `x <- c(1.45, 3.465, 7.0000004, 9.89)`?

Comment: Barplots are for discrete types of data, so if the data is not evenly spaced then a barplot is not the correct type of plot.  Your question does not explain what data is or what you are attempting to show, thus it is impossible to provide a meaningful recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with @Dave2e that a barplot may not be the best way to represent your data, you can get something like what you are describing by starting with a blank plot and drawing the relevant rectangles. I am using your y values (1:4) and the x values that you mentioned in your comment. I am not sure what you want on the x-axis, but I show labels for the x-values that you give. In order to look like a barplot, I suppress the tick marks on the x-axis.

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,11), ylim=c(0,4.5), bty="n",
    xaxt="n", xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xlab="", ylab="")
rect(x-0.5, 0, x+0.5, y, col="gray")
axis(side=1, at=x, col.ticks=NA)
```

[image: Barplot-like chart]